# Subsetting rows in a dataframe based on rows in another dataframe in R

Tags: r

Just a snapshot of the data that we are working with
[image: Just a snapshot of the data that we are working with]

What I want to be able to do is to identify the blocks (BlockId) that have greater than 90% of class 5 present and then remove all of those blocks from the dataset. I started with subsetting the data with `subset(NLCD2008,Class==5 & Percent< .90)`which gave me a DF with a column with the blocks that should be removed as seen below:

```
    > dput(ids)
structure(list(BLOCKID = c(100, 131, 179, 200, 222, 236, 238, 
241, 244, 254, 257, 258, 265, 266, 27, 278, 57, 63, 69, 75, 81
), Class = c("5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5"), CA = c(22983987.0806, 
24692082.1724, 23533460.3724, 23401233.5635, 24116398.1926, 23766711.1699, 
24795140.5362, 24876914.4067, 24898552.2795, 24985030.0734, 25012822.6465, 
24993341.0278, 25041230.4987, 25049166.7966, 22372955.0846, 24737206.1697, 
24104160.9584, 24922870.2331, 24943920.0281, 24162534.823, 23096329.0313
), TLA = c(25018769.0617, 25057087.1604, 25149935.9177, 25176830.9298, 
25207224.138, 24802986.7321, 24852905.0566, 24883383.5601, 24898641.1381, 
24985030.0734, 25012822.6465, 25049866.3254, 25090169.5911, 25072609.4832, 
24830593.7725, 25144460.7117, 24935516.21, 24930068.7064, 24947519.2647, 
24961803.5077, 24974601.3436), MSI = c(1.69665962298056, 1.31048429936865, 
1.33110171648693, 1.36242160001161, 1.27666751812728, 1.22789953816493, 
1.26867391259833, 1.25128851571841, 1.18533526393745, 1.18792224187668, 
1.18520978795299, 1.39406482047182, 1.24884906769663, 1.24939571303602, 
1.31731564029142, 1.59900472213938, 1.38890295951441, 1.20315890311899, 
1.18325402703837, 1.27998393051198, 1.47485350719615), Percent = c(0.918669780432366, 
0.985433063880751, 0.935726454707888, 0.929474945784445, 0.956725661682217, 
0.958219726785611, 0.997675743730222, 0.99974002115169, 0.999996431186766, 
1, 1, 0.997743489052367, 0.998049471438513, 0.999065008107126, 
0.901023764859709, 0.983803409161585, 0.96665979382185, 0.999711253370988, 
0.999855727675293, 0.967980331050461, 0.92479270093409)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I would like to do from here is take 21 unique block ids from this subset and remove them from the original data. So this subset identified blocks 27,57,63.... as unsuitable blocks and I would like to be able to take that list and remove them from the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
NLCD2008[ !(with(NLCD2008, Class==5 & Percent > .90)), ]
```

using `subset()`

```
# remove all blocks that contain greater than 90% of class 5 from NLCD2008 dataset.
subset(NLCD2008, !(Class==5 & Percent > .90))

# get filtered block ids   
ids <- subset(NLCD2008, Class == 5 & Percent > 0.9)
# remove the block ids from original data.
NLCD2008[!(NLCD2008$BLOCKID %in% unique(ids$BLOCKID)), ]
```